# Confusion between dot and title in contents

Tags: table-of-contents

I have a confusion in the toc between the title and the dots.

```
 \documentclass[oneside]{book}

    \usepackage{color, xcolor}


    \newcommand{\mysection}[2]{
        \setcounter{section}{#1}
        \setcounter{section}{0}
        \chapter*{#2}
        \addcontentsline{toc}{section}
    {\protect\numberline{\hspace{-1.15cm}%
                       \colorbox{blue!50}{\color{blue}\string\parbox[c][.72em]{1em}
                       {\strut\protect}}%
                       \hspace{1em}\bfseries\sffamily \MakeUppercase{#2}\protect}}
    }




    \begin{document}

    \tableofcontents

    \frontmatter
    \mysection{1}{Introduction}
    \mysection{0}{Acknowledgments}
    \mainmatter


    \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Your `\colorbox` leaks into the title region, as far as I can see. There are better ways to achieve such things with `tocloft`, for example

Comment: What are you trying to achieve here? You're using a `\section`-like interface yet you're setting a `\chapter`... Could you elaborate?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of a bunch of `\protect` commands and a strange `\string` macro there, it's better to use a robust command for such things since exandability of the command is no issue here!

However, `\chapter*` and using `section` as formatter indicator for the ToC still looks weird.

```
\documentclass[oneside]{book}

\usepackage{xcolor}

\usepackage{tocloft}

\renewcommand{\cftsecindent}{0pt}  % Perhaps?

\DeclareRobustCommand{\entryfortoc}[1]{%
  \bfseries\sffamily\MakeUppercase{#1}%
}

\DeclareRobustCommand{\bluenumberbox}[1]{%
  \colorbox{blue!50}{\color{blue}\parbox[c][.72em]{1em}{\strut}}%
}

\newcommand{\mysection}[2]{%
  \setcounter{section}{#1}
  \setcounter{section}{0}
  \chapter*{#2}
  \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\protect\numberline{\bluenumberbox{}}\entryfortoc{#2}}%
}



\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\frontmatter
\mysection{1}{Introduction}
\mysection{0}{Acknowledgments}
\mainmatter


\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It's quite hard to understand what you're trying to do.

1. Why should chapters in the front matter be regarded at the section level in the TOC?
2. Should the blue rectangle be typeset in the margin?
3. Why not simply a rule?
4. What's the purpose of `\setcounter{section}{#1}\setcounter{section}{0}` if the final effect is just to set the section counter to 0?

Here's a simpler code.

```
\documentclass[oneside]{book}

\usepackage{xcolor}

\DeclareRobustCommand{\bluerectangle}{%
  \hspace*{-3.5em}%
  \textcolor{blue!50}{\rule{1em}{.72em}}%
  \quad
}
\newcommand{\mysection}[1]{%
  \stepcounter{section}% reset all child counters
  \setcounter{section}{0}%
  \chapter*{#1}
  \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{%
    \bluerectangle\bfseries\sffamily\MakeUppercase{#1}%
  }%
}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\frontmatter
\mysection{Introduction}
\mysection{Acknowledgments}

\end{document}
```

[image]